# Generate odd number to be added as parameter into sql statement vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, parameters

I am currently working in vb.net windows form applications with an sql back end. I am trying to use a for loop to write odd numbers into an sql column starting with 1 and moving up the amount of rows in a datagridview. However, my For statement is not giving me the next step and depending on my for loop placements I either miss the loop to write my rows into my sql database or i miss the odd number. Here is my code:

```
 For cn As Integer = 0 To Datagridview1.RowCount - 1
        Dim StartTime As Date = Datagridview1.Rows(cn).Cells(1).Value
        For i As Integer = 1 To cn
            'sql code
            Try
                Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                    conn1.Open()
                    Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (@col1, @col2, getdate(), 5, @col5)", conn1)
                        With comm1.Parameters
                            .AddWithValue("@col1", StartTime)
                            .AddWithValue("@Col2", Combobox1.selectedvalue)
                            .AddWithValue("@Col5", i)
                        End With
                        comm1.ExecuteReader()
                    End Using
                    conn1.Close()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        Next
    Next
```

Comment: where are the odd numbers supposed to come from?  is it `i` or the CBO?  that i loop looks like it is repeating/overwriting.  `For cn As Int32 = 1 ... Step 2` might work better

Comment: I think that the repeating and overwriting is whats going on. The odd numbers are coming from the variable i.

Comment: @Plutonix I changed the code to "for i as int32 = 1 step 2" and it did not work. I can not change the variable cn to a step 2 because it is reading rows down a dgv and I will only get every other row.

Comment: when `cn` is working on row 13, the `i` loop is going to insert 12 new rows(?).  How is it avoiding dupes?   Rather than that `i` loop just pick a random odd number maybe?  `Dim rVals = {1, 3, 5, 9...}`  `thisVal = rnd(maxRValsYouSpecify)` maybe

Comment: @Plutonix A duplicating error could be occurring, when i run the code the odd number is always 1. I can not use a random odd number because I am generating a list of parts I need an operator build, and they need to build it in the order of the odd numbers. An example could be the datagridview has 5 rows with 5 different parts to build. I need the numbers to appear in col5 as 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

Comment: Ok, using `i` like that it seemed like you wanted something almost random.  Look at  `Datagridview1.Rows(cn).Col5` and add 2 to the value (assuming they are sequential)?

Comment: i = (cn * 2) - 1 ? and no internal loop?

Comment: @Steve I think that just might work, I will need to put in an if statement to get around the 0 so I dont get a negative 1.

Comment: Nope, you could just start with cn=1 and adjust for the row indexing. Answer below,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your requirements you could just write something like this

```
For cn As Integer = 1 To Datagridview1.RowCount 
    Dim StartTime As Date = Datagridview1.Rows(cn-1).Cells(1).Value
    Try
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (@col1, @col2, getdate(), 5, @col5)", conn1)
                With comm1.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@col1", StartTime)
                    .AddWithValue("@Col2", Combobox1.selectedvalue)
                    .AddWithValue("@Col5", (cn * 2) - 1)
                End With
                comm1.ExecuteReader()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
Next
```

As a side note, please read [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: If i do this should i rewrite line 1 of code as: "For cn as integer = 1 to datagridview.rowcount"...Or else will it skip my row 0 in my datagridview rows?

Comment: This answer works, Thanks Steve, Also thanks Plutonix for your help.